# How to display custom checkout billing field in WooCommerce admin single orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, orders

During the checkout process, under Company, I have another field for Company Registration Number. Now, everything works fine, the field is correctly saved under each order but I was wondering how can I display the company registration number under company name when I open the order in the admin panel.

PS: field name is `billing_cif`

[image: Order meta in WooCommerce Admin Panel]

Comment: Normally We expected you to provide in your question your own real code attempt. As there is some existing code for it as an official WooCommerce code snippet *(but with an error)*, I have answered bellow exceptionally. Other more elaborated ways (but more complicated) requires from you a real code attempt in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this WooCommerce snippet](https://gist.github.com/woogists/fba058890c3a49f649fc6fe8eb9ddf7c#file-wc-display-custom-checkout-field-order-php) found in [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#section-6) *(where there is a little mistake)*, try the following:

```
/**
 * Display field value on the order edit page
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('My Field').':</strong><br>' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'billing_cif', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

You need to be sure that the correct `meta_key` under wp_postmeta table is `billing_cif` as it could be saved also like `_billing_cif` instead.

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

---

Or the same thing in a better way since WooCommerce 3:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta( $order ){
    $billing_cif = $order->get_meta('billing_cif'); // Get custom field value

    if( ! empty( $billing_cif ) ) {
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('CIF reference').':</strong><br>' . $billing_cif . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works too.